# Run PHPUnit test when saving file in PHPStorm

Tags: php, git, phpunit, phpstorm, githooks

I have configured PHPUnit on PhpStorm Version 8.0.3 and I was asking myself if it would be possible to run a Test each time I save a file or push it with git.

I searched on Google but didn't find any info about this.

I know it's possible to run the test manually after pushing it with git, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Isn't it too late if you launch the test after the push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can use `pre-push hook`.

But i think better don't do it...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why shouldn't i use it?

Comment: Count of tests continuously grow, and it will take more and more time, and it can annoying... In some case when you need to push fix of some bug ASAP - you should be update and test too, and it can become terrible pitfall. Moreover it's little bit unclear... And i think nice configured CI can provide more transparent and more flexible opportunity to ensure that code in repo tested by phpunit...

Comment: Thank's for the explanation :)